# Compile C++Builder VCL project with gcc?

Tags: gcc, c++builder

We have been asked if our C++Builder VCL program could be compiled using gcc on linux.  I don't believe this is in order to run the code, but to evaluate it using HP Fortify.  I can't imagine how such a thing could be done, but most of you folks are smarter than me, perhaps someone can think of a way.

Thanks!

Comment: If it uses Embarcadero-only language extensions, then no ... the first thing you would have to do is get rid of all of those.  Actually I try to design my VCL apps so that the program logic is in Standard C++, and the user interface is separate, and a main file links the two together.  Then you can at least run standard analysis tools on the standard part.

Comment: The VCL needs binary compatibility with Delphi and it uses extensions only the Borland/Embarcadero compilers have. So no, no chance. You can of course do what M.M says, create an interfacing layer, but the VCL part would have to be C++Builder or Delphi.

Comment: Only by writing VCL wrapper ... for all the VCL stuff  code in question use ... that goes also for datatypes like `AnsiString`, ... a huge ammount of work with questionable result ... also some `*.dfm` parser to init the stuff ....